# Can we able to show the image of a product from another site

Tags: php, magento

I imported some products to my "Magento Go" site through a csv files.
How can i display the image of each product?

I know, we can add the image manually through admin side.

But instead of that , can we mention the location of image (like http://www.test.com/products/product-image.jpg)in the csv file used for importing?

Or is there any other solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send images with Web service API.

I used following snippet on one of our projects:

```
    $image_entry = ...
    $imagePath = $dir.$image_entry['nimi'];
    if(file_exists($imagePath)){
        //$sku = microtime();//$result['kood'];
        $newImage = array(
            'file' => array(
                'name'    => $image_entry['nimi'],
                'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($imagePath)),
                'mime'    => 'image/jpeg'
            ),
            'label'    => $image_entry['nimi'],
            'position' => 0,
            'types'    => array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail' ),
            'exclude'  => 0
        );
        try {
            $imageFilename = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.create', array($sku, $newImage));      
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            print( "Error assigning image to $sku: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n" );
        }
    }
```

Another option is to overwrite magento default behaviour to directly link files from another host - really bad option.

There is one more option - download images with PHP, but then you need to change import's module behaviour to download images.